# MacOS Detects Aftermarket SSD But Doesn't In Recovery Mode

Tags: disk-utility, ssd, recovery

I've been using a 2014 MacBook Pro on the latest OS (now Big Sur) successfully for awhile with an aftermarket SSD installed. I decided to clean it to give away/sell so I logged out of iCloud and iMessage, reset the NVRAM per https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496, and booted it up into recovery mode to erase the drive but discovered that recovery-mode disk utility is not detecting the boot drive, just the recovery partition. The machine still boots up normally and successfully and disk utility in the OS displays the boot drive just fine...but obviously I can't erase it from within the OS!

When resetting the NVRAM, it played the startup chime 3-4 times or so in the span of me holding down the required keys for 20 seconds.

I've already run disk utility's "First Aid" on all containers listed but the same behavior persists.

Disk utility in the OS shows an APFS System Volume and a separate APFS Data Volume that both show the same full capacity as my SSD:
[image: A screenshot of a Disk Utility window]

Any ideas on what I can do to get recovery-mode disk utility to recognize my SSD?

EDIT: This is an internal Kingston A2000 M.2 NVME SSD being used in conjunction with a Sintech NGFF M.2 nVME SSD adapter.

In the recovery environment, the terminal commands `diskutil list` and `diskutil apfs list` output:

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
  0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *1.3 GB     disk0
  1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk0s1
  2:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        1.3 GB     disk0s2
/dev/disk1
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
  0:                            untitled               *5.2 MB     disk1
/dev/disk2
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
  0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk2
/dev/disk3
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
  0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk3
/dev/disk4
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
  0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk4
/dev/disk5
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
  0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk5
/dev/disk6
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
  0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk6
/dev/disk7
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
  0:                            untitled               *6.3 MB     disk7
/dev/disk8
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
  0:                            untitled               *2.1 MB     disk8
/dev/disk9
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
  0:                            untitled               *1.0 MB     disk9
/dev/disk10
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
  0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk10
/dev/disk11
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
  0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk11
/dev/disk12
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
  0:                            untitled               *1.0 MB     disk12
/dev/disk13
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
  0:                            untitled               *6.3 MB     disk13
-bash-3.2# diskutil apfs list
diskutil: did not recognize verb "apfs"; type "diskutil" for a list
```

Comment: What you're seeing in Disk Utility is normal.  We need to see what you see when in *Recovery*.  When booted into Recovery, go into Terminal and issue the command `diskutil list` and `diskutil apfs list`.  [Edit] your post with the updated info.  Is this a USB drive or a 3rd party NVMe/PCIe drive? Who is the mfg?

Comment: Thanks for your time - I've updated the original post with that information.